# bash: sqlplus: command not found

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, linux

I have installed oracle correctly and also set ORACLE_HOME correctly on server,still sqlplus command is not working in my PC while it is working in others PC. I think I missed out some important step can you tell me what should I do ?

```
 $ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
```

This following is error message:

```
$ sqlplus
bash: sqlplus: command not found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Export the PATH variable. You have missed that.

```
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Comment: There are also other variables which can be useful - ORACLE_SID, ORACLE_BASE (amongst others) - see [here](http://sabdarsyed.blogspot.ie/2008/09/setting-oracle-environment-variable.html).

Comment: @Mat Still not working.I think there should be about loading the environment variables and that but I don't know how to load environment variables..

Comment: Edit your .bashrc and then run the command "source ~/.bashrc". That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your Unix `bash` config file `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, and add the following to it:

```
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You'll need to open a new shell to see the changes take effect.

That will modify the setting for just the current user. If you want to make the changes applicable to all users system-wide, put the above lines in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

copy and paste as it is:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib  
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
```

Answer (score -1):

```sh
$ export ORACLE_HOME=/u1/db/db1800/product/18.0.0/dbhome_1
$ export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ export ORACLE_SID=PDB
$ sqlplus sys/sys@PDB as sysdba
```

This should work

Comment: [While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837) Welcome to the network :)

Comment: This doesn't really add anything that the existing answers have already stated.